# Switch case with enum causes repetition

Tags: java, switch-statement

When I iterate through a simple Enum tester with a for-each loop and a switch statement to output the enumerated value, I see behavior that seems strange to me.

Code:

```java
public class EnumTest {

    private Number number;

    public EnumTest(Number number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public enum Number {
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE,
        FOUR,
        FIVE;
    }
    private void tellItLikeItIs() { 
        switch (number) {   
            case ONE:
                System.out.println("ONE");
            case TWO:
                System.out.println("TWO");
            case THREE:
                System.out.println("THREE");
            case FOUR:
                System.out.println("FOUR");
            case FIVE:
                System.out.println("FIVE"); 
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        for (Number n : Number.values()) {
            EnumTest et = new EnumTest(n);
            et.tellItLikeItIs();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    ONE
    TWO
    THREE
    FOUR
    FIVE

    TWO
    THREE
    FOUR
    FIVE

    THREE
    FOUR
    FIVE

    FOUR
    FIVE

    FIVE
```

Why does each call return itself and all subsequent values?

Comment: I'm surprised your compiler isn't warning you about this. What are you using to compile?

Comment: Stupid question. I'll answer it below. Funny how the minute I post is the minute I realize the answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I dont think javac warns about missing breaks

Comment: @stas: Gosh, I could have sworn it did. Another vote for using a pickier compiler (Eclipse will warn, for example - at least optionally).

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno SR2 with a 1.6-compliant compiler.

Comment: @stas It's possible to configure the eclipse compiler to warn about this.

Comment: @CannonPalms: I suggest you go into "Errors / Warnings", and review all of the "Potential programming problems". You can turn this into a warning or an error.

Comment: I just checked and (at least by default on my machine) eclipse does not warn about it. I, however, have not updated it in a couple months, which I will do now come to think of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you forgot the `break;` statements...

```
private void tellItLikeItIs() { 
        switch (number) {   
            case ONE:
                System.out.println("ONE");
                break;
            case TWO:
                System.out.println("TWO");
                break;
            case THREE:
                System.out.println("THREE");
                break;
            case FOUR:
                System.out.println("FOUR");
                break;
            case FIVE:
                System.out.println("FIVE"); 
                break;
        }
    }
```

Read more about the switch statement [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> Without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use Enum.name() or Enum.toString() method,like below:

```
    private void tellItLikeItIs() {
     System.out.println(number.name());
    }
```

or

```
    private void tellItLikeItIs() {
    System.out.println(number);
    }
```